# Unicode Characters in QT Designer for Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I am writing a gui for an executable. My first one was written using Python and TKinter. It worked. Now I am working on version 2, and I want to do it in QT4. I found the Qt Designer which is really helpful for creating the layout etc.

I created a QLabel, and in there I want it to display a greek Gamma Symbol.

But how? I did not find any way to do this. There is a button I can press and there appears to be an option to write "source code". But what does it accept? I tried different methods:

- u"\u03B3"
- `&gamma;`
- and a couple more.

If I write the &, the text changes its color to red, in the source code editor. But it will still just display the text I typed in.

Is this at all possible, or I just write some placeholder and then change it to Gamma in the python code itself?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QLabel` supports HTML, for this you must right click and select the option `Change rich text...` and in the tab `source` place html code:

```
<p>&gamma;</p>
```

That is, within the tags `<p> </p>` obtaining the following:

[image]

Comment: And if we want to change it from the script and not inside Qt, I assume something like `my_qlabel.setText("<p>&gamma;</p>")` would work?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work for other widgets such as pushbutton in Qt Designer. The general solution is to copy the unicode directly from some tool such as Charater Map on Windows:

[Search and copy an icon of a font family](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfGVb.png)

There are also online tools that can show icons and allow you copy the icons, for example [Nerd Font](https://www.nerdfonts.com/cheat-sheet).

Here is an example of my use case:

[Example of the github icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjNgz.jpg)